# Get radiobutton and save it in a ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have a `SavingsAccount` Class which Extends my other class called `BankAccount`, I also have `CheckingAccount` which also Extends my `BankAccount` class

In my SavingsAccount, I have this:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName, double initBalance) {
    super(accountNo, accountName, initBalance);
}

public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName) {
    super(accountNo, accountName);
}
```

}

In my NewAccount Frame, I have an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<BankAccount> list = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
```

AccountType was in a radiobutton: Savings and Checking, if savings is selected it will get that and save it in the ArrayList. How can i get this?

I have this, but theres an error:

```
if(rad_savings.isSelected()){
    list.add(rad_savings.getText());
} else {
    list.add(rad_checking.getText());
}
```

Comment: And what was wrong with the answers from your **[previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805472/calling-accountno-accountname-in-arraylists)** question?

Answer (score 1):

This is extension of my previous answer.There  are many mistakes.

You cannot get text from `RadioButton`.

Take a `boolean` in `field` to decide weather its `savings` or not.

```
BankAccount account= new BankAccount();
account.setAccountnumber(txt_accountnumber.getText());
account.setAccountname(txt_accountname.getText());
if(rad_savings.isSelected()){
    account.isSavings(true);
    }
else{
    account.isSavings(false);
    }
list.add(account);
```

Comment: There's an error, symbol: method isSavingsAccount(boolean)
location: variable account of type BankAccount

What do you this error means? I've extended SavingsAccount class in my BankAccount class.

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute called **accountType** in your **BankAccount**  class. Not sure how your BankAccount class is but you may add the new attribute like this:

```
class BankAccount {

    /**
     * Other attributes and their getter and setter
     */

    //accountType
    String accountType;

    public String getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }

    public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }


}
```

Create an arraylist of BankAccount as:

```
List  <BankAccount>bankAccountList = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
```

When you get the radio button selected, do something like this considering you have an BankAccount reference created:

```
//somewhere in your code
BankAccount account = null;

if(rad_savings.isSelected()){
                   account = new SavingAccount();
                   account.setAccountType("saving");
                   list.add(account );
    }
    else{
        account = new CheckingAccount();
        account.setAccountType("checking");
        list.add(account);
        }
```

Then wherever you retrieve the account, you can always check the type and process accordingly.

Comment: Hello Juned, can you cite an example for 'add an attribute called accountType' so we can in the same page.

Comment: There's an error:
`if(rad_savings.isSelected()){
                account = new SavingsAccount(); //here
                account.setAccountType("savings");
                list.add(account);
        }`




in my BankAccount Class:
`public class BankAccount {
    private String accountNo;
    private String accountName;
    protected double balance; 
    private String accountType;

    public String getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }

    public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }`

Comment: No suitable constructor found for SavingsAccount()

`if(rad_savings.isSelected()){
                account = new SavingsAccount(); // in this line
                account.setAccountType("savings");
                list.add(account);
        }`


In my Savings Account:

`public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

    public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName, 
            double initBalance) {
        super(accountNo, accountName, initBalance);
    }

    public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName) {
        super(accountNo, accountName);
    }
    
}`

Comment: " no suitable constructor found in SavingsAccount()
constructor SavingsAccount.SavingsAccount(String, String) is not applicable.
(actual and formal arguments lists differs in length)

Below is my SavingsAccount:

`public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

    public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName, 
            double initBalance) {
        super(accountNo, accountName, initBalance);
    }

    public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName) {
        super(accountNo, accountName);
    }
    
}
`

Comment: JVM adds a default constructor if there is no consturctor defined in your class. But if you have defined few instructors then it is the programmers responsibility to add a default constructor i.e a constructor with no args. Do like this  public SavingsAccount();

Comment: Is the below differ from what you mean?

`public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

    public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName, 
            double initBalance) {
        super(accountNo, accountName, initBalance);
    }

    public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName) {
        super(accountNo, accountName);
    }
    
}`

Comment: Use this: public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {public SavingsAccount(); public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName, double initBalance) { super(accountNo, accountName, initBalance); } public SavingsAccount(String accountNo, String accountName) { super(accountNo, accountName); } }

Comment: @JunedAhsan - sorry for bothering, but still there was an error.
`public SavingsAccount();` // in this line, it says "Missing method body, or declare abstract

Comment: My bad : Use it like this public SavingsAccount() {};